# Libgdx Actor undetected touch input

Tags: java, libgdx, touch, actor

I am looking for touch detection. The code showed below is what I did to set a circle in my app. I want detect touch on this circle and not around or on the entire texture. The strange thing is that touch isn't detected, in nowhere I can detect it
**Circle class:**

```
public class Circle_Obj extends Actor{
    private Vector2 position;
    private float radius;

    private com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle circle;
    private Texture texture;

    public Circle_Obj(float x, float y, float radius) {

        position = new Vector2(x,y);
        this.radius = radius;

        circle = new com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle(x,y,radius);
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("texture.png"));

        addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("TOUCHED", " TOUCHED ");
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(texture,0, 0);
}
}
```

**Screen class :**

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;
    private Circle_Obj circle_obj;

    public GameScreen() {
        circle_obj = new Circle_Obj(Static_values.Width/2, Static_values.Height/2, Static_values.Width / 100 * 10);

        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(Static_values.Width/3, Static_values.Height/3));
        stage.addActor(circle_obj);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.draw();    
        }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        }
/** other methods **/
}
```

Comment: did you try just "stage = new Stage();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libgdx's touch detection in a circle class.Only touched circle will affected.

```
    public boolean is_touched() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        float xx = Gdx.input.getX();
        float yy = Gdx.input.getY();
        float x = position.x;
        float y = position.y;
        return (xx - x) * (xx - x) + (yy - y) * (yy - y) < radius * radius;
    }
}
```

If you are using a lot of circles so it is better for performance to take touch position as a parameter.

in the circle class

```
public boolean is_touched(float xx,float yy) {
            float x = position.x;
            float y = position.y;
            return (xx - x) * (xx - x) + (yy - y) * (yy - y) < radius * radius;
        }
    }
```

and in another class

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            float xx = Gdx.input.getX();
            float yy = Gdx.input.getY();
            if (circle0.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                // do something about circle0
            }
            if (circle1.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                // do something about circle1
            }
            if (circle2.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                // do something about circle2
            }
        }
```

You can also ignore one of the touched circles when two circles overlaps and user touchs the overlapping area.

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                float xx = Gdx.input.getX();
                float yy = Gdx.input.getY();
                if (circle0.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                    // do something about circle0
                }
                else if (circle1.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                    // do something about circle1
                }
                else if (circle2.is_touched(xx, yy)) {
                    // do something about circle2
                }
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work EDIT : "> radius * radius"; is wrong, the correct is "< radius * radius"

Answer (score 0):

To detect the touch on an actor added in a Stage, the method `hit` of the actor is called ([hit detection in the documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#hit-detection))

```
public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    if (touchable && getTouchable() != Touchable.enabled) return null;
    return x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height ? this : null;
}
```

You have not set a size to your `Circle_Obj` actor, so `hit` will always return null.

Now, your actor is a circle, so you probably want to override `hit` so that it checks if the given coordinates ares in the circle instead of the default implementation that checks if the coordinates are in a box of the size of the actor.

Something like:

```
@Override
public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    if (touchable && getTouchable() != Touchable.enabled) return null;
    return (x - position.x)*(x- position.x) + (y - position.y)*(y - position.y) < radius*radius ? this : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit from Actor, you need to set the bounds or it will not be click/touch-able!.
        Simply set the bounds to match the texture your Actor contains.

```
    //add this Set bounds the x, y, width, and height
    circle_obj.setBounds(0, 0,texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
```